Property '' does not exist on type {}
I am creating peer-to-peer payment built on Polygon network. I have attempted various solutions such as adding any but to no avail.
the full error message
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"80002"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property '80002' does not exist on type '{}'.

PaymentToken is imported from ../abis/PaymentToken.json
const loadWallet = async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        const web3 = window.web3;
        var allAccounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        setAccount(allAccounts[0]);
  
        // Here is the error
        const paymentTokenData: any = PaymentToken.networks['80002'];
        if (paymentTokenData) {
          var paymentTokenInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
            PaymentToken.abi,
            paymentTokenData.address
          );
          setPaymentToken(paymentTokenInstance);
          var bal = await paymentTokenInstance.methods
            .balanceOf(allAccounts[0])
            .call();
          setBalance(bal);
        } else {
          window.alert("TestNet not found");
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        window.alert("Non-Eth browser detected. Please consider using MetaMask.");
      }

../abis/PaymentToken.json
"networks": {},
  "schemaVersion": "3.4.16",
  "updatedAt": "2024-07-05T12:57:25.623Z",

update:
The JSON object contains the ABI of our contract. This ABI and JSON file is created by truffle when we run the truffle compile command. The ABI contains all the information like the address of your contract on the blockchain, what functions are present in the contract, and the parameters and returns types of these functions.
How to populate this field to successfully load the wallet.
contracts/PaymentToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract PaymentToken is ERC20 {
    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC20("Payment Token", "Pay") {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}


The error implies that the imported JSON does not contain any properties inside networks, which is likely an error you would want to fix, as you are trying to access a property called 80002.
However, if you are only looking for a way to silence the TS linter, you can say const networks = PaymentToken.networks as {[key: string]: any};, and then access the network you want const paymentTokenData = networks['80002'];.

I get this error 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693) 

My bad, use {[key: string]: any} instead of {[key: string] => any}.

The front-end isn't working as expected since PaymentToken.networks does not contain the value expected. Any idea on how to fix the issue rather then silence the TS linter? I have updated the question with more details.

This makes the question specific to truffle. I suggest you post a new question on how to specify networks in a truffle contract.
